# C++ creating an array of classes and printing it

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I want to creat an array of classes and print it.

right now my approach is:

1. Create two different classes
2. Use aggregation
3. Use a function to create an array of one of those classes
4. Use a function to print that array
5. All functions have to be type void

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int invsize = 5;

//first class:
class Item {
    private:
        //i'm supposed to have all values set to private
        string itname;
        int itpower;
        int itlasting;
    public:
        //this is so I can create an array of those classes later:
        Item(string i, int j, int k) { itname = i; itpower = j; itlasting = k; }
        //a method to print this class:
        void itprint() {cout << itname << itpower << itlasting;};
        ~Item(){};
};

//second class:
class Player {
    private:
        string plname;
        int plrole;
        int plbrain;
        int plbrawn;
        //aggregation:
        Item * Inventory;
    public:
        void plprint();
        Player();
        ~Player();
};

//a Player constructor, in which I want to create the array of "Items" also:
Player::Player() {

    /*I'm adding info to the Player class first, it works fine and is irrelevant to my question so I didn't paste it here*/

    //now I'm creating an array of Item classes and giving them values:
    Item Inventory[4] = { Item("generic name", 5, 5), Item("generic name", 5, 5), 
               Item("generic name", 5, 5), Item("generic name", 5, 5) };    
}

//a method to print the Player class and the "Inventory" array:
void Player::plprint() {

    /*printing the info about the Player class here first, again, works fine and is irrelevant so I didn't copypaste it*/

    //printing the "Inventory" array:
    cout << "Your inventory contains:" << endl;
    for (int i=1;i<invsize;i++) {
        Inventory[i].itprint();
    }
}

//and finally the main:
int main () {

    //creating a Player class - as I understand, the "Inventory" array should get created with it   
    Player * firstPlayer = new Player;
    //printing the created object and its inventory
    firstPlayer->plprint();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles, and when I run it, it seems to create the Player class correctly, it also prints the info about the player just fine, and then something goes wrong with the array and the whole thing crashes.

I'm sure I just can't understand something here. I'd be very grateful for any kind of help. I googled a lot but couldn't find any relevant tutorials or answered questions. Thank you in advance! Also, excuse my bad english, it's my second language.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Why don't you step through every line in your code using a debugger, locate the problem and then post the line or block of code that's causing the problem. This will make it easier for us to assist you.

Comment: `now I'm creating an array of Item classes and giving them values:` -- Note that the array you're creating is local.  It no longer exists after the return of the `Player` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems to create the Player class correctly

No, It didn't.

```
Player::Player() {

/*I'm adding info to the Player class first, it works fine and is irrelevant to my question so I didn't paste it here*/

//now I'm creating an array of Item classes and giving them values:
Item Inventory[4] = { Item("generic name", 5, 5), Item("generic name", 5, 5), 
           Item("generic name", 5, 5), Item("generic name", 5, 5) };
```

}

You are creating an array of Item called Inventory in your Player constructor, that is a local variable, not referring to your member variable Inventory.

So, when your constructor end, the local array Inventory will be destroyed...

By the way, why do you use a pointer for an array of Inventory? You can do that easily by using an array itself.

> then something goes wrong with the array and the whole thing crashes.

```
void Player::plprint() {

/*printing the info about the Player class here first, again, works fine and is irrelevant so I didn't copypaste it*/

//printing the "Inventory" array:
cout << "Your inventory contains:" << endl;
for (int i=1;i<invsize;i++) {
    Inventory[i].itprint();
}
```

}

It is because you are counting and printing your array from 1, array should start from 0. so you should use `for (int i = 0; i < invsize - 1; ++i) {/*...*/}`
**Important, in C++ or almost all programming language, arrays start from 0**

You are missing default constructor for class Item, so if will give you an error when you are trying to declare Item Inventory or Item Inventory [4]

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int invsize = 5;

//first class:
class Item {
private:
    //i'm supposed to have all values set to private
    string itname;
    int itpower;
    int itlasting;
public:
    //this is so I can create an array of those classes later:
    Item() {};
    Item(string i, int j, int k) { itname = i; itpower = j; itlasting = k; }
    //a method to print this class:
    void itprint() { cout << itname << " " << itpower << " " << itlasting << std::endl; };
    ~Item() {};
};

//second class:
class Player {
private:
    string plname;
    int plrole;
    int plbrain;
    int plbrawn;
    //aggregation:
    Item Inventory [4];
public:
    void plprint();
    Player();
    ~Player();
};

//a Player constructor, in which I want to create the array of "Items" also:
Player::Player() {

    /*I'm adding info to the Player class first, it works fine and is irrelevant to my question so I didn't paste it here*/

    //now I'm creating an array of Item classes and giving them values:
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        Inventory[i] = Item("generic name", 5, 5);
    }
};

//a method to print the Player class and the "Inventory" array:
void Player::plprint() {

    /*printing the info about the Player class here first, again, works fine and is irrelevant so I didn't copypaste it*/

    //printing the "Inventory" array:
    cout << "Your inventory contains:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<invsize - 1; i++) {
        Inventory[i].itprint();
    }
}

//and finally the main:
int main() {

    //creating a Player class - as I understand, the "Inventory" array should get created with it   
    Player * firstPlayer = new Player;
    //printing the created object and its inventory
    firstPlayer->plprint();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains a lot. That array mistake... yeah, embarassing, can't believe I didn't notice that. This was very helpful, you're a blessing! I have one more question - in the corrected code you posted, is it still true that the array doesn't exist outside of the Player constructor?

Comment: @phoiboss no, the array will exist as long as the Player object exist. C++ variables are tied to scope, in your example, Inventory was declared in Player object's constructor, so it will only exist in the constructor and destroyed once the constructor is finished. Now, Inventory is declared in Player class, so it will exist in Player class scope, as long Player object exists, it will exists